# Textfield with centered text with Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, titanium

How to make textfields in Titanium with centered text? Is it possible using Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `textAlign:'center'` property in the constructor/createTextField. I know this isn't in their API docs but it might just work [this bug report](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20) seems to say that the property should have been added. (at least in the latest [RC 1.7.0](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.7.0.RC1/Titanium.UI.TextField-object.html)) it is how ever not in the API docs but this might have simply been an omission.

Give it a try comment if it works or doesn't if it does then maybe you should ping them to update the docs

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `paddingLeft` as a property?

Comment: @brian-huenefeld I tried to use this property, but did not work. I will check if there is something wrong in the code, but I guess that not. Hope it is not something standard. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: I'm not sure but I would think `paddingLeft: '50%', paddingRight: '50%'` would work if the paddings are working... you never really know with their documentation :-/

Comment: @brian-huenefeld paddingLeft and paddingRight did not work. One more bug :/